# No provider for Storage! (DBService -> Storage) in ionic2

Tags: typescript, angular, ionic2

**This is my app.ts**

[image]

**This is my service.ts**

[image]

I getting No provider for Storage! (DBService -> Storage) error. I believe there is something wrong at my service.ts,
1) Is it my constructor no parameter?
2) I cant use this.storage inside getTasks() function, even cant use this.storage in constructor as well, why is it?

Please help me as i stuck for 1 day already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [Working Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rrBOK0wFTCMg2jqZdEbh?p=preview)

## Using `this`

It looks like your function in service.ts can't access your `storage` variable that was set in the constructor.

Instead of `let storage` in your constructor try `this.storage` like this:

```
constructor() {
    this.storage = new Storage(SqlStorage);
}
```

Then you can access it from any function in the same class like this

```
setColor(newColor) {
  this.storage.set('color', newColor);
}
```

## Storage Methods

Also, from the [Ionic docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/LocalStorage/) I don't see a `query` method, but there is a [`get(key)`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/LocalStorage/#get) and [`set(key, value)`](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/LocalStorage/#set) option that should be useful.

## Adding Providers

With Ionic 2/Angular 2 services need to be setup in the [providers](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#!#injector-providers) section of your component. This can be on your global app.component if you want the service available to the entire app, or you can just make it available to a single component.

In the Plunker example I set this up in home component where it says `providers: [DBService]` like this:

```
// home.ts
import { Page } from 'ionic-angular/index';
import { DBService } from './service.ts';

@Page({
  templateUrl:"home.html",
  providers: [DBService]
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your time to setup the working example!
1) This is the one that does the trick, constructor(public dbService: DBService) {} in service.ts
2) For storage method, http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/api/platform/storage/SqlStorage/
it got the query method.

Thanks adriancarriger willing to lend me a hand.

Comment: Cool, glad it helped and thanks for the link about the `query` method!